# Search and focus on windows in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The Command Palette (CMD + P) is great for finding and opening files in a given project. However, is there anything similar for searching through all open windows in Visual Studio Code?

Let's say I open VSC for a project in `projects/Alphabet` and another in `projects/Twitter`. Then I would love to be able to hit a hotkey that opens a search window. When I type in `tw` it should list the `Twitter` project and when I press enter, it should focus on that VSC instance.

I found a generic solution as an Alfred Workflow (https://github.com/jnewland/alfred-open-windows), but while it works in most instances, it currently does not work for Visual Studio Code (https://github.com/jnewland/alfred-open-windows/issues/5).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a relatively new feature called "Switch Window" that does exactly this - narrow down search on all open instances. Just search with `cmd+shift+p` for it or bind `workbench.action.switchWindow` to a shortcut of your liking (its not bound to a key by default).

Comment: In mac the default shortcut is ctrl+W